# Getting randomly non English character in SQL

Tags: database, ms-sql

Getting some random non English character when I execute **DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS WITH ALL_CONSTRAINTS** in MS SQL database.

Some time it's work or some time not.

Some errors are :

> The multi-part identifier "t䁟1.TaxID" could not be bound. DBCC
>   CHECKCONSTRAINTS failed due to an internal query error.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'N䁕LL'. DBCC execution completed. If DBCC
>   printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'SalesOrd䁥rID'.
>   Msg 2509, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS failed due
>   to an internal query error.

I have checked DBCC Checkdb but no error found.